# PHP function in HTML

Tags: php, html

I have a form for tracking an investment's performance.

[image]

The code looks like this:

```
<form style="margin-top: 60px" action="" method="post">
    <p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name of Investment</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><select name="">
                    <?php 
                        $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT deal_name FROM tbl_deal';
                        $result = mysqli_query($DBconnect, $sql);

                        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
                        {
                            echo "<option value=''>Select Investment</option>";
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                            {
                                 echo "<option value='$row[0]'>$row[0]</option>";   
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo "<option value=''>No Investments Found</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th colspan="2">Year 1</th>
            <th colspan="2">Year 2</th>
            <th colspan="2">Year 3</th>
            <th colspan="2">Year 4</th>
            <th colspan="2">Year 5</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>$</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>$</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>$</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>$</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>$</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>January</th>
            <td>
                <select name="">
                    <option value="">Distribution Received</option>
                    <option value="">Return of Capital</option>
                    <option value="">Capital Call</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="" size="5"></td>
        <td>
                <select name="">
                    <option value="">Distribution Received</option>
                    <option value="">Return of Capital</option>
                    <option value="">Capital Call</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="" size="5"></td>
        <td>
                <select name="">
                    <option value="">Distribution Received</option>
                    <option value="">Return of Capital</option>
                    <option value="">Capital Call</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="" size="5"></td>
        <td>
                <select name="">
                    <option value="">Distribution Received</option>
                    <option value="">Return of Capital</option>
                    <option value="">Capital Call</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="" size="5"></td>
        <td>
                <select name="">
                    <option value="">Distribution Received</option>
                    <option value="">Return of Capital</option>
                    <option value="">Capital Call</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="" size="5"></td>
        </tr>
```

...and so on for everything month.  As you can see, it's very repetitive.  I tried making a PHP function to at least minimize the dropdown menu's redundancy, but I get an 'unexpected <' error.

It seems that the HTML tags are giving me problems?
Any advice how to write PHP functions containing HTML?
Any other advice on minimizing the redundancy?

Comment: *"but I get an 'unexpected <' error."* - You have many `<`, which line does it say it's on?

Comment: *"I tried making a PHP function"* - Which function is that?

Comment: There's also no closing `</form>` tag.

Comment: You may have a blank item in your database which is outputting nothing and causing  "'unexpected <' error."

Comment: `<select name="">` Give it a name if you ever want to see the selected item back in your PHP EG `<select name="deal_name">`

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask].

Comment: You likely want `echo "<option value='".$row[0]."'>".$row[0]."</option>"; `

Comment: Also nest a loop from 0 to 11 with 0 to 4 inside. Use the outer counter in a date call to get the month

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan, using a nested loop made everything so clean and concise! I also realized from your previous comment that I was not concatenating correctly. I will post the new code in the answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The new and concise code:

```
<?php
echo '
<table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th colspan="2">Year 1</th>
            <th colspan="2">Year 2</th>
            <th colspan="2">Year 3</th>
            <th colspan="2">Year 4</th>
            <th colspan="2">Year 5</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>$</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>$</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>$</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>$</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>$</th>
        </tr>
        ';

            $months = array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
            $distribReceived = 1;
            $returnCapital = 2;
            $capitalCall = 3;
            $category = "category";
            $amount = "amount";

            //Loop for each month
            for($monthNum = 0; $monthNum < 12; ++$monthNum)
            {
                 echo '<tr>
            <th>'. $months[$monthNum] .'</th>
            ';

            //Loop for each year
                for($year = 1; $year < 6; ++$year)
                {

                echo '
                <td>
                    <select name="'.$months[$monthNum].$year.'">
                        <option value="'.$distribReceived.'">Distribution Received</option>
                        <option value="'. $returnCapital .'">Return of Capital</option>
                        <option value="'. $capitalCall .'">Capital Call</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="'.$amount.$months[$monthNum].$year.'" size="5"></td>
                ';
                }
                echo '</tr>';

            }

          echo'  </table><p>';

            ?>`
```